# Is there any way to take a .js widget that can normally be used in HTML, and run it for javascript in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to take a .js widget and basically use it for google sheets. Currently from this website(https://www.wowhead.com/tooltips), you can copy

```
<script>var whTooltips = {colorLinks: true, iconizeLinks: true, renameLinks: true};</script>
<script src="http://wow.zamimg.com/widgets/power.js"></script>
```

into any html and it will create a mouse-over tooltip for links related to that website. Is it possible to somehow create a script in Google Sheets to be able to do this within sheets?

I am aware of the ability to create my own tooltips, however that would be too time consuming and not what I'm looking for.

I've looked all over the website listed and they have several guides for multiple applications and usages across forums, message boards etc but nothing pertaining to javascript or google sheets in particular. I did find a code.google.com/archive for wowtooltips but it had no code at all..

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried Tampermonkey?

Comment: I hadn't tried it before but I just tried it out. If I'm understanding correctly you take the code of the .js page and just paste it into a new script on tampermonkey? This gave me errors and it wouldn't run the script. Even though I know the power.js works from that page as it is used in hundreds of forums/websites. Maybe I misunderstood something though with it.